# Php условие в echo

Tags: php

Есть код

```
 $end_result     .= '<tr><td><a href="show.php?id='.$r['id_item'].'">' . str_ireplace($word, $bold, $result) . '</a></td><td>'.$r['id_category'].'</td><td>'.$r['item_infinity'].'</td><td>'.$r['item_type'].'</td><td>'.$r['item_user'].'</td><td>'.$r['item_type'].'</td><td>'.$r['item_cost'].' руб.</td></tr>';
```

Как создать внутри него условие? к примеру if ($r['id_category'] == 0) { что-то написать }

Comment: Тернарный оператор:

    echo 'A', (X ? 'B' : 'C') , 'D';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это называется тернарный оператор.

```
echo $r['id_category'] == 0 ? 'ветка then' : 'ветка else';
```

Comment: <td>'.(($r['id_category'] == 4)?"Категория":"").'</td>
 
так заработало. не получается убрать else (:""), без него не работает

Comment: @Rammsteinik - вы, как программист, как узнали что-то новое, первым делом должны прочитать документацию(!).

>Начиная с версии PHP 5.3 также стало возможным не писать среднюю часть тернарного оператора. Выражение expr1 ?: expr3 возвращает expr1 если expr1 имеет значение TRUE, и expr3 в другом случае.

Использование этого способа в вашей ситуации только запутает код, так что рекомендую оставить с пустой строкой как есть. Вы ставите скобки в выражении что бы понимать где оно начинается и заканчивается? Пользуйтесь автоформатирование кода, в phpStrom это комбинация клавиш CTRL+ALT+L

Comment: @Rammsteinik - Если вы не пользуетесь PhpStorm - то я настоятельно рекомендую Вам начать им пользоваться как можно скорее.

Answer (score 0):

Код будет читаемее, если вместо `echo` воспользоваться ф-ей [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php) – у вас будет отдельно html темплейт, и в него, там где `%s` впечатаются соотв. значения.

`%s` – это место для текстовой строки, есть ещё варианты для чисел и пр. - смотрите документацию.

```
$tmpl = <<<EOF
    <tr>
        <td><a href="show.php?id=%s">%s</a></td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s руб.</td>
    </tr>
EOF;

$end_result .= sprintf(
    $tmpl,
    $r['id_item'],
    str_ireplace($word, $bold, $result),
    $r['id_category'] == 0 ? "на случай нуля" : $r['id_category'],
    $r['item_infinity'],
    $r['item_type'],
    $r['item_user'],
    $r['item_type'],
    $r['item_cost']
);
```

[работающий пример](http://ideone.com/VYaNoY)